# Emoticons using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, emoticons

I am creating a facebook-like chat Smiley/emoticons as such:

```
<div class="chat">
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <div><button id="">Click to Load Emoticons</button></div>
</div>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
var smileys = {
    ':)': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-)': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':D': '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    ':-(': '<img src="smilies/angry.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'angel': '<img src="smilies/angel.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'arrow': '<img src="smilies/arrow.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    'at': '<img src="smilies/at.gif" border="0" alt="" />'
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chat > textarea").bind("keyup", function(e) {
        $(".chat .preview").html(emoticon($(".chat > textarea").val()));
    });
});

function emoticon(msg) {
  msg = msg.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');

  for (var key in smileys) {
    msg = msg.replace(key, smileys[key]);
  }

  return msg;
}
```

I want a situation when a button is clicked just like facebook let it load all the smiley images and on selecting any let it bind it to the textarea field. But at this point dont know how to improve further. Please help!

Comment: Hey Patrick, it is best if you show what you have tried so far. You risk getting your question put on hold because you do not have an example of what you've tried.

Comment: What is the function `smilyMe` doing?

Comment: Let me modify my code the better!

Comment: "But at this point dont know how to improve further" what isn't working about your code? what part do you need help on?

Comment: What do you think is not optimal? What should be improved? If you are asking what improvements could be made, you should rather ask at [codereview.SE]

Comment: Try the [twemoji](http://twitter.github.io/twemoji/) library (by Twitter). It's great and makes using emoji on the web really easy!